# Pause script until command in other script is executed [Bash]

Tags: bash, unix

In script a I tell script b to execute a certain command.
Is there a way to pause script a until script b is done executing?
I don't want to use sleep, because every run of the script can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
wait <pid>
```

This will cause script A to wait for B to complete before continuing.

Comment: How can I catch the pid of script B in script A?

Comment: Once you have spawned the process, "echo $!" will return the pid